# Is there a i18n solution build in Doctrine2

Tags: php, internationalization, translation, doctrine-orm

we're looking for a i18n behavior in Doctrine2. Is there any standard implementation? Or do you know a very easy and fast solution?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: Why would there be one? Do you just want translated error messages? Otherwise this doesn't sound part of its purpose.

Comment: no, we need to translate all table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Translateable behavior for Doctrine2. I've never used it and can only link you to the docs for that:

- http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#translatable

Note that the article relates to Doctrine2 Beta4 ORM and contents might not have made it to the stable release of Doctrine2. However, in the comments to http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-0-0-alpha3-released jwage suggests an i18n behavior will be part of Doctrine2.

Comment: Nice, thank you - we'll try the library. the github project https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions is active

Answer (score -1):

I think that is out of the purpose of Doctrine.